# web based solution for create plot from LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, plot, big-list

We know there are some solutions for rendering LaTeX mathematical content on the web, for example [MathJax](http://mathjax.org).  Is there a similar (free) way to create plot for mathematical formula which is written as LaTeX? For example plots of ƒ(x) versus x. Open source libraries are preferred (I need to use it in an application).

Note: I do not mean graph-theory graphs.

Comment: Is something like [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com) or [Plotly](https://plot.ly) what you're after? They have nothing to do with LaTeX of course.

Comment: I think using Gnuplot or similar software inside your application could be better to use. It does not rely on online apis then where you probably would have some call limitations.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh But GNUplot needs plain text notation. I mean if you ask that to plot `x=\cos u+\frac{1}{2}`, it cannot and you have to ask to plot `x = cos(u) + 1/2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[The Function Grapher](http://www.tlhiv.org/mpgraph/) by Troy Henderson is powered by MetaPost version 1.9991 (TeX Live 2016) at the time of writing this answer and it allows one to plot different sorts of functions (one variable, two variables, parametric, etc).

Comment: +upvote. I could not open linked address. But the word `function grapher` help me a bit.

Comment: linked page does not understand all mathematical controls. For example it does not understand `frac{}{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you could use Wolfram Alpha's API to generate plots.

Try reading here:
https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation/

Comment: It is very goof but unfortunately its free access is limited to 2000 call per month.

Comment: I think that it's possible to write a script that writes TeX code, and then using TikZ/PGFPlots, you could write programatically the graph, with the software save the file to where you want, and then just insert an `<img>` from the path that the script created.

Doing that wouldn't be very hard. You just need to do some text parsing to open the file programatically, print code (text) into it, and then save it.